# Ordering Arguments of Antisymmetric Functions in Cyclic Way

Tags: replacement, sorting

I have two functions ang and sqa, each of which take two arguments which must be distinct integers between 1 and 6. For instance I could have `ang[2,1]` or `sqa[3,6]`.

Both of these functions are antisymmetric i.e. `ang[a,b] == -ang[b,a]` and `sqa[a,b] == -sqa[b,a]`, and for reasons that aren't important I'd like to write a replacement rule (or any other implementation) so that if I have a product of angs and sqas which can be turned to the form `ang[a,b]sqa[b,c]ang[c,d]sqa[d,a]` or
`ang[a,b]sqa[b,c]ang[c,d]sqa[d,e]ang[e,f]sqa[f,a]`
(note the cyclic arguments of alternating ang/sqa, in specific arrangement ab bc cd de ef fa or ab bc cd da) then the antisymmetry of the ang and sqa should be used to do so. For instance if I had `ang[1,2]sqa[3,2]ang[3,6]sqa[4,6]ang[5,4]sqa[5,1]`
then I'd want to flip the order on the `sqa[3,2]`, `sqa[4,6]` and `ang[4,5]` to rewrite this as `-ang[1,2]sqa[2,3]ang[3,6]sqa[6,4]ang[4,5]sqa[5,1]`

Obviously there will be multiple ways to flip the signs to get things into the nice cyclic form, and I don't care which is used. I've tried very naive algorithms like just applying `//. {ang[a,b]sqa[a,b] :> -ang[a,b]sqa[b,a]}` but this doesn't always work for obvious reasons. I'm wondering if there is some clever way to use e.g. Sort to do this, but I'm coming up blank...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a graph with all allowed edges (going both ways), then find a [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path):

```
makecycle[F_] := Module[{c, h},
  c = Join @@ Cases[F,
    (f : ang | sqa)[u_, v_] -> {{DirectedEdge[u, v], f[u, v]},
                                {DirectedEdge[v, u], -f[v, u]}}];
  h = FindHamiltonianCycle[Graph[c[[All, 1]]]][[1]];
  h /. Rule @@@ c]
```

Try it out:

```
makecycle[ang[1, 2] sqa[3, 2] ang[3, 6] sqa[4, 6] ang[5, 4] sqa[5, 1]]

(*    {ang[1, 2], -sqa[2, 3], ang[3, 6], -sqa[6, 4], -ang[4, 5], sqa[5, 1]}    *)
```

Multiply them to get the overall sign:

```
Times @@ %
(*    -ang[1, 2] ang[3, 6] ang[4, 5] sqa[2, 3] sqa[5, 1] sqa[6, 4]    *)
```

Unfortunately, `Times` is [`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) and so the cycle is reordered automatically. Maybe [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) could be useful too; it depends on what you are going to do with the result and what format you ultimately need.